# Loop wont stop, even with limit set (count++)

Tags: loops, count

I just cannot seem to get this to stop looping after the count (5) is reached. IT just keeps asking away. IS there something I'm not seeing?
Any help is greatly appreciated. 
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        double answer = 0;
        int randomInt1;
        int randomInt2;
        randomInt1 = (int)(1 + Math.random() * 10 - 1 +1);
        randomInt2 = (int)(1 + Math.random() * 10 - 1 +1);

```
    //System.out.println("Please answer the following problem: ");
    //System.out.println(randomInt1 + "+" + randomInt2 + "=");
    //answer = keyboard.nextDouble();


    count=1;

    while(count < 5)
    {
     System.out.println("Please answer the following problem: ");
    System.out.println(randomInt1 + "+" + randomInt2 + "=");
    answer = keyboard.nextDouble();   

    if(answer != (randomInt1 + randomInt2))
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, that is not correct.");
         count++;
         break;
    }
    if(answer == (randomInt1 + randomInt2))
    {
        System.out.println("Nice!");
        count++;
        break;
    }


    }
    return answer;
    }

       }
```

****UPDATED

```
    count=0;
    while(count < 5)
    {
     System.out.println("Please answer the following problem: ");
    System.out.println(randomInt1 + "+" + randomInt2 + "=");
    answer = keyboard.nextDouble();   

     if(answer != (randomInt1 + randomInt2))
    {
     System.out.println("Sorry, that is not correct.");
    }     
     else if(answer == (randomInt1 + randomInt2))
    {
     System.out.println("Nice!");
    }
     count++;
     break;
    }

    return answer;
```

Comment: Why using `break` in every if condition? And `return answer` in while? What does `While` work for?

Comment: Would you like for me to post the full code? It is another public static.

Comment: if `answer == (randomInt1 + randomInt2)`, it will break loop from the second if condition. And else `answer != (randomInt1 + randomInt2)`, it will break loop from the first if condition.  I have not seen it will continue ask not stop.

Comment: I have updated, see above current edit

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `break` on your code. Use `else` instead of the second `if` statement. Also, you should better indent your code. It helps reading.

If you want to count 5 times, you should do:

```
count = 0; 
while(count < 5) { 
  ...(your code here)
}
```

Comment: Without the break option, it asks the same question over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you increase `count` outside the `if` condition.

```
count = 0; 
while(count < 5) { 
  if(condition1){
      // ...
  }
  else{
      // ...
  }
  count++;
}
```

Update:
Below is the complete code, which may be like what you want.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        double answer = 0;
        int randomInt1;
        int randomInt2;
        randomInt1 = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 10 - 1 + 1);
        randomInt2 = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 10 - 1 + 1);
        while (count < 5) {
            System.out.println("Please answer the following problem: ");
            System.out.println(randomInt1 + "+" + randomInt2 + "=");
            answer = keyboard.nextDouble();

            if (answer != (randomInt1 + randomInt2)) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, that is not correct.");
            } else if (answer == (randomInt1 + randomInt2)) {
                System.out.println("Nice!");
                break;
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it outside. still no joy. wont stop at 5

Comment: @S.Adelman I update my answer with a runnable code, which can stop after 5 wrong answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! Been at this for 4 hours :/